# Can I automatically pre populate excel using Crystal Reports?

Tags: excel, crystal-reports-2008

Hello guys I have never used Crystal Report before and have literally no idea how it works. This Credit Union I work for wants me to automatically update columns of their excel worksheet from the database system I was wondering if Crystal Reports would be able to do the trick. If so ill try learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal can't do this on its own, but there are 3rd-party tools you can use with Crystal that can do this. Visual Cut by Millet Software can run a Crystal Report and fill a specific range in a spreadsheet. Of course that means learning Crystal and Visual Cut.